# IMA：How to include file signatures in the measurement list?

Tags: ima

We can use IMA-appraisal to ensure the authenticity and integrity of the application (signature-based appraisal), but how do we include the signature value of the file in the measurement list?As shown in the following：

I have turned on the ima-sig option in the startup command line, but the measurement list still has only the hash value, not the signature value, is this required for secure boot? Or other configurations in the .config?